# Expectation of dot product of Distance from $\hat{\beta}$ to $\beta$

Tags: statistics

When I was reading the thesis named 'Ridge Regression: Biased Estimation for Nonorthogonal Problems', I was struck by a below problem.

$$
\hat\beta \text{ is an estimator of linear regression coefficients and } \beta \text{ is a population parameter}\\
L_1 = \text{Distance from }\hat\beta\; \text{to}\; \beta \\
L_1^2 = (\hat\beta - \beta)^T(\hat\beta - \beta) \\
E[L_1^2] = \sigma^2\;\text{Trace}(X^TX)^{-1}
$$
My question is, Why $E[L_1^2] = \sigma^2\;\text{Trace}(X^TX)^{-1}$? I couldn't prove this part. So I'd like to ask for someone's help. Thank you for reading and I respect your hard work.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at their paper, they assume a linear model of the form

$$\underbrace{Y}_{n\times 1}=\underbrace{X}_{n\times p}\underbrace{\beta}_{p\times 1}+\underbrace{\epsilon}_{n\times 1},\quad E[\epsilon]=0,E[\epsilon\epsilon']=\sigma^2 \mathbb{I}_n$$

where $X$ is a fixed matrix of regressors, and $\beta$ is a fixed vector of parameters.

The OLS estimator is given by

$$\hat\beta\equiv (X'X)^{-1}X'Y\\
=\beta+(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon.$$

Notice the OLS estimator is unbiased for $\beta$, and we have

$$E[(\hat\beta-\beta)'(\hat\beta-\beta)]=\text{tr}E[(\hat\beta-\beta)(\hat\beta-\beta)']\\
=\text{tr}E\left[(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon\epsilon'X(X'X)^{-1}\right]\\
=\text{tr}\left((X'X)^{-1}X'E\left[\epsilon\epsilon'\right]X(X'X)^{-1}\right)\\
=\text{tr}\left((X'X)^{-1}X'\sigma^2 \mathbb{I}_nX(X'X)^{-1}\right)\\
=\sigma^2\text{tr}(X'X)^{-1}\\
$$

Comment: Really, thank you for your effort!!